# How to copy specific subfolders if existing to new folders in a backup folder using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am a total beginner and I need some help to backup some folders with files from a server.

I need to copy some folders to my local computer.

Folders to copy are like this

```
\\DistantServer\path\RandomFolder\Config\old
\\DistantServer\path\Another Random Folder\Config\old
...
```

Those old folders should be copied to:

```
D:\Backup\RandomFolder\old
D:\Backup\Another Random Folder\old
```

I tried some codes, but I'm only having errors.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file should work for the task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=\\DistantServer\path"
set "TargetFolder=D:\Backup"

for /D %%I in ("%SourceFolder%\*") do (
    if exist "%%I\Config\Old\" (
        rd /Q /S "%TargetFolder%\%%~nxI\old" 2>nul
        %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%I\Config\Old" "%TargetFolder%\%%~nxI\old\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
    )
)

endlocal
```

The command **FOR** searches in source folder as defined with environment variable `SourceFolder` for non hidden subfolders. Each subfolder found is assigned with full path not ending with a backslash and never enclosed in double quotes to loop variable `I` referenced with `%%I`.

The command **IF** checks for existence of the subfolder `Config\old` in current subfolder of source folder. The found subfolder is ignored if not containing the subfolder `Config\old`.

On existence of `Config\old` in current subfolder of source folder the command **RD** first removes quietly with all subfolders the appropriate target folder independent on its existence to make sure that the copy done next results in 1:1 folder copy. The **RD** command can be removed in case of target folder most likely never exists before the copying is done or if it is wanted that existing contents of target folder is merged with current contents of source folder.

`%%~nxI` references the current subfolder in source folder without path, i.e. without folder path as defined with environment variable `SourceFolder`.

The command **XCOPY** copies the entire folder `Config\old` in current subfolder of source folder to a subfolder `old` in target folder as defined by environment variable `TargetFolder`. The entire directory structure to appropriate target folder is automatically created by **XCOPY** if not already existing because of target specification ends with a backslash being a clear indication for **XCOPY** that the target string specifies a directory.

**Note:** The entire code above without command **RD** could be optimized also to a single command line.

```
@for /D %%I in ("\\DistantServer\path\*") do @if exist "%%I\Config\Old\" %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%I\Config\Old" "D:\Backup\%%~nxI\old\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
```

Single command line with command **RD**:

```
@for /D %%I in ("\\DistantServer\path\*") do @if exist "%%I\Config\Old\" rd /Q /S "D:\Backup\%%~nxI\old" 2>nul & %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%I\Config\Old" "D:\Backup\%%~nxI\old\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>nul` and `2>nul`. And read answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&` as used in the last batch code (single command line with **RD**).